# Finding the Lateral Distances between two GPS Points

Tags: matlab, math, localization, gps, distance

I have two Set of GPS Points recorded from High Precision GPS Receivers which travels from Point A to Point B . please see the Image attached.

Black Point is the GPS points of Vehicle 1 and its path... Blue Point is the GPS Points of Vehicle 2 and its path.  Vehicle 2 should follow the same path as Vehicle 1 , But there exists some deviation in pratcical scenerios. So. I need to Caluculate how much deviation it has .

I am trying to find the lateral distance between the vehicle 1 and nearest vehicle 2 GPS Point.

What I did till now ?

*)  Since vehicle 1 is ahead of vehicle 2  and , vehicle 2 reaches vehicle1 (approx)  after some time (say buffer as 5 ~10 seconds ).... 
   I am calculating the arc distance between  Vehicle 1 GPS Point and a set of Vehicle 2 GPS Points (buffer)  and finding the minimum of those Arc Distances.

*) By finding the Minimum of Arc Distance , I am finding the GPS Point which is nearest to the vehicle 1 GPS Point.. now , I am stuck at finding the Lateral Distance between these two GPS Points in an effecient manner.

Please let me know if u have any questions or comments on my procedure.. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume both routes start from the same position. so i would do the  following:

1. Resample each route to get a new set of points with a known sampling step from on another (You can interpolate the new points from the old see for example https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/278615-how-to-create-points-set-on-2d-polyline)
2. Once i have two sets of points that start from the same location and are in a constant sampling step just calculate the distance between each corresponding points.